# Is it pythonic to use the '__main__' mechanism to test the module?

Tags: python, coding-style, idioms

Suppose we have the following module:

```py
# my_module.py

def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = my_sum(2, 3)
    print(s)
```

How bad / good / pythonic is it to test my modules or parts of them like that?

EDIT: I'm not saying or asking whether everything should be tested like that. What I mean is, if I am lazy and the module is not critical, would it be an idiomatic way to get things done quickly?

Comment: You will go crazy trying to test a huge codebase like this, thus unit tests are used instead. Plus, tests are almost always put in separate files.

Comment: Check out the built-in [unittest module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

Comment: This doesn't look pythonic, nor aligned to any software engineering practices. I'd suggest to try out some testing framework. As mentioned above – unittest, or my personal favourite [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/) are nice options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one? The [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts) state:

> This [adding the `if __name__ == '__main__': ...` block] is often used either to provide a convenient user interface to a
> module, or for **testing purposes** (running the module as a script
> executes a test suite).

Comment: Nice, but I'm curious to hear more from experienced Python users, whether they had problems or happiness with such approach.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's pythonic because it's done in python. I would suggest you look at pytest but python is for beginners and everyone does thing their way.